# Using More than three values in a query to send an email

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a query which I use in sending email in ASP.net, but in the existing code i can only use two columns from the query in the email:

1. Email (email)
2. Firstname (emails).

   ```
   emails[Convert.ToString(reader["email"])] = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]);
   ```

Now i want to improve the code so i can use

1. Email
2. Firstname
3. Program

This is my previous code that retrieves two columns

```
  SqlDataReader reader;

  string sendMessage = "SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email,      User_Profile.FirstName, User_Profile.Program FROM aspnet_Membership join User_Profile on User_Profile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId";


        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sendMessage, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);

            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emails[Convert.ToString(reader["email"])] = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]);
            }

            foreach (string email in emails.Keys)
            {
              //email codes
            }

        }
```

This is what i have tried

```
    public class EmailCode
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Program { get; set; }
    }


    protected void emailtest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlDataReader reader;
        string sendMessage = "SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email,      User_Profile.FirstName, User_Profile.Program FROM aspnet_Membership join User_Profile on User_Profile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sendMessage, myConnection);


            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();



            var emails = new List<EmailCode>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emails.Add(new EmailCode
                {
                    Email = Convert.ToString(reader["email"]),
                    FirstName = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]),
                    Program = Convert.ToString(reader["Program"])
                });
            }

            foreach (EmailCode email in emails)
            {

                const string username = "";
                const string password = "
                SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                MailAddress fromaddress = new 
                smtpclient.Host = "";
                smtpclient.Port = 25;
                mail.From = fromaddress;
                mail.To.Add(Email);
                mail.Subject = ("");
                //mail.Attachments.Add(new mail);
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = Hello" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FirstName) + " you are studying " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Program) + ";

                smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
                smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
                smtpclient.Send(mail);
            }
```

Comment: Create a class and assign the Email, Name and Program to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You can either stop using a dictionary all together, or use a dictionary where the Value of it is a class, such as a [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is an example using a new type. After updating your SQL query to return the `Program` data, you could do something like this.

```
//Create a new class for our Poco
public class EmailCode
{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Program {get;set;}
}
```

```
var emails = new List<EmailCode>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    emails.Add(new EmailCode {Email = Convert.ToString(reader["email"]),
        FirstName = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]),
        Program =  Convert.ToString(reader["Program"])
        });
}

foreach (EmailCode email in emails)
{
  //email codes
}
```

---

In your "What I've tried" edit, you need to access the properties off of the email variable exposed from the loop, like this (not to mention you have syntax errors):

```
mail.Body = "Hello" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.FirstName) + " you are studying " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Program);

smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
smtpclient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: thanks, but i keep getting  "The name 'Email' does not exist in the current context"when i do something like  |mail.To.Add(Email);|

Comment: @Jack Edit your question to include the code of what you have tried.